# Changing the IP address for urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to change the IP address from which my simple python code connects to my website.

```
import urllib.request  as urllib2
# change of IP address
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/").read()
```

Is there a python library that will easily enable it? So that the user who connects to the site displays different locations.

For example, I will want to scrape local news from the site using IP Address: 118.69.140.108 and port 53281.

How to do it, what library will enable it?

Comment: Does your python code run on a host with multiple IP addresses?  You can't just make one up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
import urllib.request  as urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": "118.69.140.108:53281"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/")
```

Alternatively you can use the `requests` library which makes it easier:

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com/"
page = requests.get(url, proxies={"http":"118.69.140.108:53281"})
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example without error handling, reconnecting. I hope I wrote the correct answer ;)

```
import urllib.request  as urllib2


http_proxy = {
    'user': ''
    , 'passwd': ''
    , 'server': '67.205.151.211'
    , 'port': '3128'
}

# change of IP address
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip").read()
print(page)

# http://username:password@someproxyserver.com:1337
http_proxy_full_auth_string = "http://%s:%s@%s:%s" % (http_proxy["user"],
                                                      http_proxy["passwd"],
                                                      http_proxy["server"],
                                                      http_proxy["port"])
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": http_proxy_full_auth_string,
                                      "https": http_proxy_full_auth_string})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
postDatas = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
             "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
             "Pragma": "no-cache"}

request = urllib2.Request("http://httpbin.org/ip", None, postDatas)

connection = opener.open(request, timeout=10)
page = connection.read()
# except Exception as err:
#     # Si il y a une erreur de connexion (timeout etc.)
#     result.add_error(err, "%s ne repond pas" % url)
# else:
connection.close()
print(page)
```