# How to change source port and ip in urllib2 request in python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, port, urllib2

[image]

while sending the urlib2 request os is choosing the source ip and port by default,
The requirement is we need to set a different port for each request using urllib2.
please refer to the attached highlighted source port captured from the pcap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the IP address for urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974628/changing-the-ip-address-for-urllib2)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the requests library
import library

page = requests.get(url, proxies={"http":"118.69.140.108:53281"})